# How to change the document template in document library?

Tags: document

I wanted my user to edit the custom fields that added in the document before uploading the document. Currently, when I add new document it forced me to upload doc first. How do I change so that it can directly go to edit page or by pass the upload window?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really work that way.  You have to upload a document first and then edit it's metadata.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing it the other way?

Answer (score 0):

If the document type is a Microsoft Office document type then you can do the following:

- set up the document library with the columns you need
- upload a document of the type you want to the document library so it gets all the columns in it's properties
- open the document from the library and save it locally as a template
- add the template to the document library as document template

Now users can select new document and get the template down to their computer. In the DIP they can add all the information before uploading the document to SharePoint.